# How do I change the transparency level of gnome-terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, transparency

I want to increase or decrease the transparency of gnome-terminal in Unity.

Answer (score 29):

Menu: **Edit** -> **Profile Preferences**

[image]

Comment: This option is no longer present for me. :-( Using gnome terminal 3.10.2

Answer (score 9):

Did you try in Terminal - Edit -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Edit -> Background ?

Answer (score 5):

On the other hand you can try CompizConfig. When you start it go to "Accessibility" and activate "Brightness, Opacity and Saturation" plugin. When you open it on Opacity tab you can set combination for mouse buttons or keyboard keys to change opacity of any active (focused) window. Default in my case was "Alt"+Scroll wheel. This is working perfectly for me. Normally I have no opacity set but when I need it I just press "Alt" and with a scroll whell adjust opacity to my desire.
Hope this will help.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. And it is general enough to apply to other terminals as well. Thanks.